# Python - Find how many digits a number is accurate to?

Tags: python, string, math, pattern-matching

I am working on a few different algorithms to calculate certain numbers, such as PI. What is a way to count the number of digits it is accurate to?

i.e.

```
real_pi = 3.141592
calc_pi = 3.141259
accuracy(calc_pi, real_pi) = 4 #i.e. accurate to 4 places
```

I cannot seem to find the right substring function (what if 1415 repeats for example? a substring way near the end would not be right, if it is meant to check near the beginning.)

Comment: Is it accurate to 3 places or 4 places in this example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you hinted at a substring way of doing this:

```
In [39]: real_pi = 3.141592

In [40]: calc_pi = 3.141259

In [41]: sum(1 for _ in itertools.takewhile(lambda t:t[0]==t[1], zip(str(calc_pi), str(real_pi))))
Out[41]: 5
```

Comment: elegant solution. +1

Comment: It's still beyond me of why OP would want to do this in a substring way :(

Answer (score 1):

In python, math.pi has the most exact pi you can hope for. You could subtract the difference between their math.pi and your pi and take the negative of the log to see how accurate it is.

```
import math
fake_pi=3.1415
print -math.log10(abs(math.pi-fake_pi)) #not sure which is greater
```

Comment: Thanks this makes sense. On testing, 3.141589 and 3.14159 both return 5.4 and 5.5 or thereabouts respectively, how would I be more concise?

Comment: Just tested it, I'm getting  5.43728021469, and 5.57616621196

Comment: I wonder if I get the length of the calculated pi, and get a substring of that length of the real pi, it'd prevent these fractions (what does 5.4 digits vs 5.5 digits mean for accuracy? what is .4 of a digit? Maybe rounding down makes more sense?)

Comment: Rounding down gets you the digit accuracy. .4 of a digit makes since when you consider that a digit is just a coefficient of a exponent with base 10. If you want the substring of correctness, you can use the -math.log(stuff) number above, round down, and that's how many digits it's accurate to. If you want a print out, convert your fake_pi to a string, then take str(fake_pi)[:2+digit accuracy], and that should print it out. (the 2 is for the 3 and the decimal point.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be comparing strings for accuracy .. and pi is surely longer than 6 digits.
Better design would be to to use round(value, digits) and compare for equality.
e.g. my_pi = 3.14, actual_pi = 3.1
if  round(my_pi,1) == actual_pi:
   print "1"

Answer (score 0):

According to your definition of accuracy:

```
def accuracy( real_pi, calc_pi ):
    str_real_pi = str( real_pi )
    str_calc_pi = str( calc_pi )
    correct = 0
    for i in range( len(str_real_pi) ):
        if str_real_pi[i] != str_calc_pi[i]:
            break
        correct += 1
    return correct - 2

real_pi = 3.141592
calc_pi = 3.141259
print(accuracy(calc_pi, real_pi))
# prints 3, meaning 3 digits are correct after the dot
```